# Process.Start não carrega as dependências do executável

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei um código que abre um programa, porém o programa precisa das DLLS/Pastas - na pasta que está localizado, então quando executo ele da erro, pois parece que não está pegando as DLLS/Pastas (se eu executo normal, abre normalmente o programa).

Será que tenho que usar o processo `Stream` em vez de `FileDialog`?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Programa (*.exe)|*.exe";

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos pensar na sua aplicação como `meuapp.exe` e o processo a ser executado de `subprocesso.exe`.

`meuapp.exe` está localizado em `C:\vinicius\meuapp.exe` e `subprocesso.exe` está em `C:\foo\subprocesso.exe`. Além de `subprocesso.exe` a pasta `foo` contém todas as dependências do subprocesso, as bibliotecas vitais para sua execução.

De forma simplificada, quando você roda `Process.Start(@"C:\foo\subprocesso.exe")`, esse arquivo é executado como se estivesse na raiz de quem o chamou. No caso, ele é executado como se pertencesse à `C:\vinicius`.

Para resolver esse problema, vamos criar uma instância de objeto do tipo `ProcessStartInfo` e *setar* a propridade `WorkingDirectory` para `C:\subprocesso\`. Ao invés de usar o *overload* de passar o caminho em string como parâmetro do método `Process.Start`, usarei o `ProcessStartInfo` que nos permite dar algumas informações a mais para a execução do processo.

```
ProcessStartInfo paramProcesso = new ProcessStartInfo();
paramProcesso.FileName = "subprocesso.exe";
paramProcesso.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\subprocesso\";
Process.Start(paramProcesso);
```

Dessa forma, o diretório de execução do subprocesso será a pasta raiz dele mesmo, que contém as suas dependências (no seu caso as DLLs).

Comment: Consegui obrigado, queria só +1 coisa, abrir o CMD no caso, e executar o comando IPConfig quando for aberto.

Comment: @Vinicius https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779667/6241184