# Como enviar para o cmd do windows a senha de administrador

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho o código abaixo em .Net escrito no Visual Studio 2019, que faz a ativação do windows. O problema é que ao rodar no comando propmpt do windows que roda com uma conta de admin do AD ele pede a senha, e isto não estou conseguindo enviar pelo programa/código. Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda nesta situação?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = “cmd.exe”;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = “runas /user:dominio\usuario slmgr.vbs -ipk aqui serial”;

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: só o `"runas"` já executaria como admin... o usuário que vai rodar essa aplicação não tem o privilégio?

Comment: o usuario é adm. mas não preciso informar a senha?

Comment: aqui deu de boas... mas o que você pode fazer também é ao invés dos argumentos informar no `StartInfo`

Comment: Qual propriedade do startinfo? poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: No meu aqui não ativou não. Quando testei pelo prompt do windows direto pediu senha, então acho que no código está pedindo também. Não deu para ver isso debugando.

Answer (score 2):

Se o usuário que está rodando a aplicação tem o privilégio de admin basta declarar o verbo `"runas"`... mas Você consegue passar as credencias de autenticação com o domínio no `ProcessStartInfo` também.

E para rodar o processo com as credencias é necessário configurar o `UseShellExecute` como `false`

```
    var senhaSegura = new System.Security.SecureString();
    var senha = "senhaDoUsuario";

    foreach (char c in senha)
        senhaSegura.AppendChar(c);



    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        UserName = "usuario",
        Domain = "dominio",
        Password = senhaSegura,
        Verb = "runas",
        Arguments = "slmgr.vbs - ipk aqui serial",
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    process.Start();
```

Comment: Está certo. mas se a minha senha estiver criptografada em um arquivo texto por exemplo em C:\temp\tempPassword.txt e a chave em C:\temp\tempKey.txt  tem como pegar ela e inserir no código acima em Password?

Comment: @user2509556 `var senha = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\tempKey.txt");`

Comment: Voltando a pergunta anterior. Eu gostaria é de criptografar a senha em um arquivo texto e descriptografar dele inserindo em password.

Comment: Outra dúvida: se eu tenho a minha senha o que coloca em Password que é uma SecureString é a minha senha criptografada?

Comment: não, mas também já é outra pergunta :P

Comment: @user2509556 a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: após fazer as alterações sugeridas recebi o seguinte erro no console:O nome do diretório é inválido!

Comment: @user2509556 que diretório?

Comment: verifiquei que tem uma diferença quando estou executando na maquina com outro usuário no caso administrador e então segui o que foi dito em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239928/process-start-n%C3%A3o-carrega-as-depend%C3%AAncias-do-execut%C3%A1vel  Informando o WorkingDirectory com isso recebi outra mensagem em que o erro parece com o anterior . A mensagem é a seguinte: Falha na inicialização do aplicativo devido à configuração lado a lado incorreta.